# VSTO Excel (C#) - Cells not automatically refreshed after changing according to arrays

Tags: c#, vsto

At first, I successfully change formulae by looping through ranges of a single cell with the following code:

```
    public static void changeFormulaOfRangeSingleCellTo(Range rangeSingleCell, string formula)
    {
            rangeSingleCell.Formula = formula;
    }
```

In order to improve calculation performance, I was trying to change formulae according to an array. The codes are:

```
    public static void changeFormulaeOfRangeAllCellsTo(Range rangeAllCells, string[,] formulae)
    {
            rangeAllCells.Formula = formulae;
    }
```

After switching methods, the cells are updated with the correct formula but resulting values are not shown. Instead, the formula, itself, is shown.

I need to enter the formula editing mode then press Enter to have the resulting values shown.

I tried the following but the cells are still not refreshed:

- change the format of the cells
- press calculate worksheet
- change the calculation type of the application
- invoke the .CalculateAll() method of the application

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer: change parameter type from string[,] to object[,]
I still don't know why... I guess it is because of the built in structure of range object...